# How can I get Table Name from BigQuery in python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I would like to get only table names from BigQuery by using wildcard in Python.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
table_names = bigquery_client.get_something().something('db_name.table_prefix_*')
```

Can I do something like this?
If I can, What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table metadata details available in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. You can run the following query and get the table names using Python SDK.

**Query:**

```
SELECT table_name FROM YOUR_DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like 'table_prefix_%'
```

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#python

Comment: Thanks. you save my day!

Answer (score 2):

I did as SANN3 taught me, like a following:

```
query = '''select table_name from my_dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name like 'table_prefix_%' '''
table_names = bigquery_client.query(query).result().to_dataframe()
print(table_names)
```

then I got table_names :-)